# PowerQuery - Import files side by side

Tags: excel, csv, powerquery

I'm getting a report for disks I/O and for some reason, the report only gives info on 100 luns at a time ... Since the report gets close to 300 luns I get free files per day for the same report. At least the disks order remains the same in each day.

So, I'm getting a few files with the following:

```
 - 01.11.2019_01.csv
 - 01.11.2019_02.csv
 - 01.11.2019_03.csv
 - 02.11.2019_01.csv
 - 02.11.2019_02.csv
 - 02.11.2019_03.csv
```

The content of each file is:

```
Timestamp, disk1, disk2, disk3, ..., disk100
Timestamp1, IOPS, IOPS, IOPS, ..., IOPS
```

each file ending 01 has the same 100 luns for each data, same goes to 02 and 03. Disks order is even the same (it helps already).

I am able to import the files into excel via powerquery, but this adds them all in sequence. Not good for me as I need to keep the order of the disks.

I've added a conditional column in PowerQuery to filter all files ending with 1, 2, and 3. Unfortunately, PowerQuery does not allow me, or at least I have yet to find a way, to use the filter to all files with column with 1 use the same columsn, all with 2 start at the column end of 1, and to the 3 the same approach.

So, at the end of the day, I'm looking to achieve this: (files are replaced by actual values)

```
- 01.11.2019_01.csv 01.11.2019_02.csv 01.11.2019_03.csv
- 02.11.2019_01.csv 02.11.2019_02.csv 02.11.2019_03.csv
```

I've tried to use transpose columns in the data import but this transposes all dates.
With the help of the the conditional columns I can filter and transpose all ending with 01 but I cannot do the same to 02 as this is gone.

Currently my only approach would be to have 3 different source connections, one for each 01, 02, 03 and then using still a separate query to get them all together in a single sheet.

Any ideas on how to achieve this without going through the previous scenario of independents connections?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you

Put all the .csv files in a single directory (here c:\directory\subdirectory)

Run annoted code below

It will read in all the csv files, append the file name on each table, then combine the tables/files

Use extra column with file name to do whatever you need to do with it, like pull out last filename character before the ".csv" by using a custom column with = Text.Start(Text.End([Name],5),1)) as the formula

```
//read all files in specified directory
     let Source = Folder.Files("C:\directory\subdirectory"),
//filter only .csv
     #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".csv")),
//Pull contents of each file into table with first row promoted as header
     #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Custom", each Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document(File.Contents([Folder Path]&"\"&[Name]),[Delimiter=",", Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),[PromoteAllScalars=true])),
//dymnamic determination of number of columns in imported data so we can expand column
     ColumnContents = Table.Column(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
     ColumnsToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(ColumnContents, each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
// expand column
     Expand =  Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom",  "Custom",   ColumnsToExpand, ColumnsToExpand),
// remove extra columns
     #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Expand,{"Content", "Extension", "Date accessed", "Date modified", "Date created", "Attributes", "Folder Path"})
     in #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you have following data:

[image]

As far as I understand you want to achieve this result (on my mind, it doesn't look handy, but since tables' structure is the same, there may be various scenarios):

[image]

Then you may use such code:

```
let
    split = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "File", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("_"), {"date", "id"}),
    transform = Table.TransformColumns(split, {"id", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ".csv")}),
    pivot = Table.Pivot(transform, List.Distinct(transform[id]), "id", "Data")
in
    pivot
```